# If input == list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So basically i'm trying to make it so that if user input is == "Blue" or "blue" it gives eye_res the value of 1. If not then give it the value of 0. What I've tried is:

```
Eye_color = input("Eye color: ")
A= (int["Blue","blue"])

if Eye_color in range (str(A)):
    eye_res = 1
else:
    eye_res = 0

print (eye_res)
```

Comment: What are you trying with the `A= (int["Blue","blue"])` ?

Comment: `print(int(input("Eye color: ").strip().lower() == "blue"))`

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you go again through your learning material or some good tutorial, that would be more efficient than trying more or less random combinations of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this does what you are looking for:

```
Eye_color = input("Eye color: ")

if Eye_color in ["Blue", "blue"]:
    eye_res = 1
else:
    eye_res = 0

print(eye_res)
```

If you want to save the list first you can also do:

```
Eye_color = input("Eye color: ")
A = ["Blue", "blue"]

if Eye_color in A:
    eye_res = 1
else:
    eye_res = 0

print(eye_res)
```

Also, if you want them to be able to capitalize 'blue' any way and `eye_res` still be 1 then you can do:

```
Eye_color = input("Eye color: ")

if Eye_color.lower() == 'blue':
    eye_res = 1
else:
    eye_res = 0

print(eye_res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare against a set value by using modifiers on the input.

```py
Eye_color = input("Eye color: ")

if Eye_color.lower() == “blue”:
    eye_res = 1
else:
    eye_res = 0

print(eye_res)
```

This makes any capitalisation of “blue” set `eye_res` to 1, while keeping the `Eye_color` variable as the exact input string.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
eye_color = input("Eye color: ").lower()

eye_res = int(eye_color == 'blue')
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what your logic in `A= (int["Blue","blue"])`
Here is the code for what you want to achieve :

```
Eye_color = input("Eye color : ")
A = ["Blue", "blue"]
if Eye_color in A:
    eye_res = 1
else:
    eye_res = 0
print(eye_res)
```

Also one-liner solution to this :

```
print(1 if input("Eye color : ").lower() == "blue" else 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can condense the answer to:

```py
eye_res = int(input("Eye color: ") in ["Blue", "blue"])
```